# How do I convert the following format to unix timestamp?

Tags: sql

The format I get from DB seems to have AM at the end. I've tried using the following but it did not work:

CONVERT(DATETIME, Sales.SalesDate, 103) AS DTSALESDATE.

CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, Sales.SalesDate, 103) AS TSSALESDATE

where Sales.SalesDate value is Apr 15 2012 12:00AM

Comment: So `[sales].[salesdate]` is definitely a varchar field?

Comment: That looks like SQLServer; are you actually using SQLServer? What version?

Comment: @Venkatramana . . . Edit your question and show sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this Query for CONVERT DATETIME to UNIX TIME STAMP
`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y 
 %h:%i%p'))`
This Query for CHANGE DATE FORMATE
`SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', 
 '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i:%p')`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2020-02-22 22:23:13.920';
           SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
            @dt AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'
                AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
```